# How can I get value from IDictionary<string, object> in VisitMember call?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I want to get property from IDictionry

I want to access it in VisitMember call

But when I run it

It seems that dictionary value is not returned

Because when I am trying to get convert as here:

```
var dictProperty = declProp as IDictionary<string, object>;
```

It returns null (but it has type IDictionary)

Where is the problem?

```
 protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
            {


                if ((node.Member as PropertyInfo) != null)
                {
                   //this line returns propety  IDictionary<string,object> of my object which Type 
                   //I can get from node.Member.DeclaringType)
                    var declProp = node.Member.DeclaringType.GetProperty(node.Member.Name);
                    ///trying to get to dictionary Item and return value
                    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDictionary<string, 
                    object>), "dict");
                    var constant = Expression.Constant("ContentType");
                    var propertyGetter = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "Item", constant);
                    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, object>>(propertyGetter, parameterExpression).Compile();
                    //but  dictProperty is null
                    //and it seems there is no value
                    var dictProperty = declProp as IDictionary<string, object>;
                    var value = expr(dictProperty);//trick to get value from dict

                }
                else if ((node.Member as FieldInfo) != null)
                {
                    var fieldInfo = node.Member as FieldInfo;
                    var constantExpression = node.Expression as ConstantExpression;
                    if (fieldInfo != null & constantExpression != null)
                    {
                       var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(constantExpression.Value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                Expression mappedMember;
                if (map.memberMap.TryGetValue(node.Member, out mappedMember))
                    return Visit(mappedMember);
                return Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, node.Member.Name);
            }
```

Comment: dictProperty is probably null because it is not able to cast declProp to a IDictionary. The declProp seems to be of type PropertyInfo as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_ since GetProperty(string) has a return type of PropertyInfo

Comment: Yes
You are right;) But it seems that I can`t get entity with values using expression visitor